# Perform a calculation with form data and parse them back to the form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, forms

I am a total noob at javascripting and yet I have a nice problem to solve.

I have a form that receives data from a database.

I wrote a very simple javascript that by itself performs the calculations I want it to do. 
But how can I get the calculated values back into the form. I want to use onkeyup so that the data is updated before the form is sent.

At this moment I only have the form, and the separate javascript. But I have no clue how to make them work together. I am aware that the `document.write` statements in the javascript won't function in the form. This, I simply used to build and check my calculator.

As soon as the `impru_rest` value will be filled in, the calculation has to start. And it has to send a new value for `impru_dobanda` and/or `impru_sold` back to the form.

Any ideas?

This is part of the form

```
<?php 
    // create form according to existing loan/interest
    echo '<td><div align="center"><input type="text" size="11" name="impru_acc" value = '.$impru_acc.'></div></td>';
    echo '<td><div align="center"><input type="text" size="11" name="impru_rest" onkeyup= value = ""></div></td>';
    echo '<td><div align="center"><input type="text" size="11" name="impru_sold" value = '.$impru_sold.'></div></td>';
    echo '<td><div align="center"><input type="text" size="11" name="impru_dobanda" value = '.$impru_dobanda.'></div></td>';    
>?
```

This is the calculation

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\">

var impru_acc = ".$impru_acc.";
var impru_dobanda = ".$impru_dobanda.";
var impru_rest = ".$impru_rest.";
var impru_sold = ".$impru_sold.";

if (impru_dobanda>0) {
    var difference = impru_dobanda-impru_rest;
    } else {
        var difference = 0;
        }

if (difference > 0) {
    impru_dobanda = impru_dobanda - impru_rest;
    document.write(impru_sold);
    document.write(impru_dobanda); 
    }

if (difference < 0) {
    impru_sold = difference + impru_sold;
    impru_dobanda = 0;
    document.write(impru_sold);
    document.write(impru_dobanda);
    }

if (difference == 0) {
    impru_dobanda = 0;
    var impru_sold=impru_sold-impru_rest;
    document.write(impru_sold);
    document.write(impru_dobanda);
}
</script>
```

After help from Allen123 and tinyByte I got this, but it doesn't do anything:

I added the jquery comment in my header now.

I'm probably making mistakes in the function, but nothing seems to happen now. I guess the script cannot influence the values in the form
This is what I have. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
            // create form according to existing loan/interetest
            echo '<td><div align="center"><input type="text" size="11" name="impru_acc" value = '.$impru_acc.'></div></td>';
            echo '<td><div align="center"><input type="text" size="11" name="impru_rest" onkeyup=calculateAll(); value = ""></div></td>';
            echo '<td><div align="center"><input type="text" size="11" name="impru_sold" value = '.$impru_sold.'></div></td>';
            echo '<td><div align="center"><input type="text" size="11" name="impru_dobanda" value = '.$impru_dobanda.'></div></td>';    
    ?>      
            <script>
        function calculateAll(){ 
        var impru_acc = $('input[name="impru_acc"]').val();
        var impru_dobanda = $('input[name="impru_dobanda"]').val();
        var impru_rest = $('input[name="impru_rest"]').val();
        var impru_sold = $('input[name="impru_sold"]').val();

        if (impru_dobanda>0) {
            var difference = impru_dobanda-impru_rest;
            } else {
                var difference = 0;
                }
            if (difference > 0) {
                impru_dobanda = impru_dobanda - impru_rest;
                }
            if (difference < 0) {
                impru_sold = difference + impru_sold;
                impru_dobanda = 0;
                }
            if (difference == 0) {
                impru_dobanda = 0;
                var impru_sold=impru_sold-impru_rest;
            }
        }
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('input').change(function(){
          calculateAll();
       });
    });
```

Comment: Why aren't you doing your calculations in php? What triggers the calculation? (PS I suspect you need jquery)

Comment: Hi Allen. I haven't found a way to do so. Do you have any suggestions? The calculation gets triggered by filling in the impru_rest field. Basically this is about a loan, interest and payment. I have to make a split in first getting the interest rate back to zero by making payments. The left over will then be taken of the saldo. And from then on the saldo will go on going down until all the payments are done. I haven't found a way to actively update the form fields in PHP.

Comment: Hi Mike, I'm not sure what you are trying to do, If the calculations need to happen after a user changes something then you must use Javascript. If this isn't the case then php would be better.

Comment: Mike that is much easier to understand now

Comment: what is the output of this function that you wrote? What do you want to achieve from this? (since your new function has no output!)

Comment: TinyByte. That is exactly my problem. My function should update the corresponding fields in my form to the newly calculated values. The new values will be entered in a database after submitting the form. So impru_acc(loan) is a fixed value, an agreed number. Impru_rest is an downpayment. Impru_sold is the left-over of the loan, but should go down only after impru_dobanda(interest) has been paid, and therefore put to 0.

Comment: TinyByte, do you have an idea for me please? Thanks so far!!!!!!! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All, I found a nice working way.
In the time between posting my question and this answer, I started learning javascripting. Not too far yet, but it gave me some eureka moments.

The form now consists of this code, and gets its values from the database:

```
echo '<input type="text" size="11" name="impru_acc" id="impru_acc" value = '.$impru_acc.'>';
echo '<input type="text" size="11" name="impru_rest" id="impru_rest" onchange="calculateAll(this.value)" value = "">';
echo '<input type="text" size="11" name="impru_sold" id="impru_sold" value = '.$impru_sold.'>';
echo '<input type="text" size="11" name="impru_dobanda" id="impru_dobanda"  value = '.$impru_dobanda.'>';
```

I made a separate calculateAll.js file and call it in my header.html file.

The calculateAll.js is based on my script in my question, but now completed including parsing values back to the form. The code consists of:

```
function calculateAll(){ 
var form = document.forms["fisa"];
var impruDobandaValue = form.elements["impru_dobanda"];
var impruRestValue = form.elements["impru_rest"];
var impruSoldValue = form.elements["impru_sold"];

var impruDobanda = parseInt(impruDobandaValue.value);
var impruRest = parseInt(impruRestValue.value);
var impruSold = parseInt(impruSoldValue.value);

if (impruDobanda > 0) {
    var difference = impruDobanda - impruRest;
    } else {
        var difference = 0;
        }
    if (difference > 0) {
        impruDobanda = impruDobanda - impruRest;
        return theForm.elements["impru_dobanda"].value = impruDobanda;
        } else if (difference < 0) {
        impruSold = difference + impruSold;
        impruDobanda = 0;
        return form.elements["impru_dobanda"].value = impruDobanda, 
            form.elements["impru_sold"].value = impruSold;

        } else if (difference == 0) {
        impruDobanda = 0;
        var impruSold = impruSold - impruRest;
        return form.elements["impru_dobanda"].value = impruDobanda, 
            form.elements["impru_sold"].value = impruSold;
        }

    }
```

But I ran into a small issue. When you make a mistake, the form did not use it's original values, but recalculates from the changed values. Which is logical. To work around this, I created a reset button for the impru_rest field in the form. It resets that field and recovers the original values of the impru_sold and impru_dobanda values in the form. After that correction is possible. I thought it was best to code this in PHP

```
<?php echo "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Reset\" onclick=\"var reset = this.form.elements['impru_rest']; reset.value = reset.defaultValue; this.form.impru_dobanda.value=".$impru_dobanda."; this.form.impru_sold.value=".$impru_sold.";\">"
?>
```

So all in all it took me a bit, but I wanted to share my findings with you.

All who responded, thanks for your help!

Mike

Answer (score 1):

write your calculations in a function and trigger it on focus out or change , like this:

```
$('input').change(function(){
   calculateAll();
});
```

UPDATE:
set 1 : include a minified jquery in your header,like:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

then use the code above in a script tag(). It's better if you put it in the end of your html markup.

don't forget to put all jQuery codes in:

```
<script>
function calculateAll(){
   //implement your logic here 
   var value1 = $('input[name="somename"]').val();
    .
    .
    .
}
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input').change(function(){
      calculateAll();
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This assumes use of Jquery. You should say so

Comment: Hi tinyByte. Could you elaborate a bit on that for me? As admitted. I am a total beginner in javascript... Thanks!

Comment: This is definitely somewhere near what the OP needs IMO. +1

Comment: @tinyByte. Shouldn't .val() being used to set here e.g $('input[name="somename"]').val(his_value_here);

Comment: val() gets the value, val('adam smith') sets value to "adam smith"

Comment: @tinyByte. How do I call this function from the form? In my original form here on top, I added for now only onkeyup remark where the function call should be put. Thanks!

Comment: you can call your functions wherever you like just: yourFunction();

Comment: Blushing here. I'm afraid this goes way over my head. :(

Comment: Please take a look at my original question, I added an attempt there.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">

    $('input').blur(function()
    {
          doCalculations();
    });


   function doCalculations()
   {

        var impru_acc = ".$impru_acc.";
        var impru_dobanda = ".$impru_dobanda.";
        var impru_rest = ".$impru_rest.";
        var impru_sold = ".$impru_sold.";

        if (impru_dobanda>0) {
            var difference = impru_dobanda-impru_rest;
            } else {
                var difference = 0;
                }

        if (difference > 0) {
            impru_dobanda = impru_dobanda - impru_rest;
            document.write(impru_sold);
            document.write(impru_dobanda); 
            }

        if (difference < 0) {
            impru_sold = difference + impru_sold;
            impru_dobanda = 0;
            document.write(impru_sold);
            document.write(impru_dobanda);
            }

        if (difference == 0) {
            impru_dobanda = 0;
            var impru_sold=impru_sold-impru_rest;
            document.write(impru_sold);
            document.write(impru_dobanda);
        }
      }   

    </script>
```

Hope this will help you...